# Best way to "stream" music / video to my HDTV from my pc?

Tags: wireless-networking, streaming, media, hdtv, media-center

My requirement is simple: I have a laptop and a desktop at home that I often use for various media (music, videos etc.) and I want to know what the best (quickest, most seamless, best quality etc) solution for sending this media to my HDTV (and connected sound system).  An example would be I'm listening to some music from youtube on my laptop in my living room and want to quickly send it to my tv (which has a sound system) so that I don't have to listen to it through my laptop.

I mainly use linux (but a windows dependent solution would be ok too if its the best option).  I would greatly appreciate any suggestions.

Oh and a wireless solution would be best.

Answer (score 1):

What I do:
windows 7 + Windows Media Center + DivX Codec(MKV/blueray) >>>>>>> Xbox360 +HDTV

also Works:
Boxee Box, 
MythOSTV box,
Original Xbox running XBMC

Comment: so your solution is "connect an HTPC box to the HDTV" where that HTPC box is Xbox360/Boxee/MythOSTV/Xbox or similar, yes?